# Prove that for any piecewise smooth curve it is possible to find the parametrisation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, plane-curves

Prove that for any piecewise smooth curve it is possible to find the parametrisation $\phi$ that is consistent with its length, ie.

length of a curve segment between $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ is equal to $|b-a|$.

It seems intuitive, but I don't have any idea how can I show this in the formal way.

Comment: Is this a question about why a reparametrization exists which respects length or about the obstructions coming from the fact that the curve is only piecewise smooth (or both)?

Comment: The first one. "a reparametrization exists which respects length"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the focus is on the existence of an arclength parametrization then, for a first step, it is convenient to assume that $\phi :[a,b]\rightarrow M$ is a differentiable curve with nonvanishing derivative. The length of that curve, restricted to $[a,t]$ is then given by
$$\ell(t) =\int_a^t |\phi^\prime(s)|\,ds $$
This is, by the assumption $\phi^\prime \neq0$, a strictly monotonic function. In fact, $\ell^\prime(t) = |\phi^\prime(t)|>0$. Therefore, by the inverse function theorem, there is a (differentiable) function $\rho: [0,\ell(b)]\rightarrow [a,b]$ such that $\ell\circ \rho (x) = x$. Also, $\rho^\prime = \frac{1}{|\phi^\prime|}$.

Now look at $\phi\circ\rho: [0,\ell(b)]\rightarrow M$. We have
$$\frac{d}{ds} \phi\circ\rho(s)=\frac{\phi^\prime}{|\phi^\prime|}$$

which is of length $1$. So with respect to this parametrization, $\int_0^c |(\phi\circ\rho)^\prime| ds = c $ is the length of $\phi\circ \rho|_{[0,c]}$

(I'm rather sure I answered exactly the same question during the last year, but cannot find that anymore. It probably got deleted by the crusaders who feel in charge of "cleaning up" this site).

Comment: Why is it $\ell(\phi)$ above instead of $\ell(b)$?

Comment: @AlkaKadri I made the mistake to use $\ell$ for both the length of the whole curve (as in $\ell(\phi)$ and the length of the curve restricted to some interval ($\ell(t) = \int_a^t$). And you are right, one fix would be to write $\ell(b)$ instead of $\ell(\phi))$.